# The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect

Tags: botframework

When connecting the emulator to the bot i get this error,

"[10:43:22] -> POST 401 [conversationUpdate]

[10:43:22] Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect."

I removed the App Id and password and tried to run it locally then also am getting the same error.

I researched around the internet and could not find any solutions that solves my problem. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have setup up an AppId in web.config file? What are the settings you have in emulator when you try to make a conversation?

Comment: i removed the app id and password from the web.config file and removed it from the emulator too still am getting this error

Comment: Don't have 2 projects running in parallel? The localhost port used is also correct?

Comment: @Azmy are you able to put your code in a repo so we can take a look?

Comment: @nicolas R no i dont have two projects running in parallel and yes the port used is also correct.

Comment: @JasonSowers no i cant put this in a repository as there are restrictions hope u understand. :)